# Does every one-one and onto analytic map on the unit disk send boundary to boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, mobius-transformation

Let $D$ be the unit disk and $f \in \text {Aut} (D).$ Then can we always say that $f(\partial D) \subseteq \partial D\ $?

What I know is that if $f \in \text {Aut} (D)$ with $f(a) = 0$ for some $a \in D$ then $f = c\ \varphi_a,$ where $c \in S^1 = \partial D$ and $\varphi_a : \mathbb C_{\infty} \longrightarrow \mathbb C_{\infty}$ is the Möbius transformation given by $$\varphi_a (z) = \frac {z - a} {1 - \overline {a} z}$$ Now let $z \in \partial D.$ Then $|z| = |\overline {z}| = 1.$ So we have $$\begin{align*} |\varphi_a (z)| & = \left | \frac {z - a} {1 - \overline {a} z} \right | \\ & = \left |\frac {\overline {z} (z - a)} {\overline {z} - \overline {a}} \right | \\ & = |\overline {z}| \left |\frac {z - a} {\overline {z - a}} \right | \\ & = 1. \end{align*}$$ This shows that $\varphi_a (\partial D) \subseteq \partial D.$ Hence $f(\partial D) \subseteq \partial D,$ since $f = c\ \varphi_a$ with $|c| = 1.$

Is my reasoning correct at all? Could anyone please check it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Looks goo to me. Note that *a priori* it does not even make sense to talk about $f(\partial D)$ when $f$ is by definition only defined on $D$. E.g., $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)$ might not exist. But thanks to knowing that $f=c\phi_a$, all makes sense and works out nicely.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen sir another similar question I have in mind in this regard $:$ Is the same true for functions in $\text {Aut} (\mathbb H),$ where $\mathbb H$ is the upper half plane?

Comment: @AntonioClaire You can map the unit disk to the upper half plane

Comment: The difference for the upper plane is that you have the point at infinity too on the boundary, so the result is true with that caveat (automorphism are now Mobius transforms with real coefficients and positive discriminant, and they usually send a finite real to infinity and infinity to a finite real)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Möbius map on open unit disk which goes to open unit disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125359/m%c3%b6bius-map-on-open-unit-disk-which-goes-to-open-unit-disk)